# How To Redirect Fb.me To Any Website?

Tags: seo, web-development, facebook, facebook-application

Is it possible to redirect fb.me for example fb.me/companyname to a different web domain altogether other than the Facebook page?

I've been investigation about this for a while now as to how it's done. 
Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually is not possible, as that domain is managed by Facebook and is intended only to refer to Facebook profiles.

Comment: People were able to do it, though. This is an example: (fb.me/VycSM8ys)

Comment: Looking at that URL, it appears to be a clean 301 redirect from `https://fb.me/VycSM8ys` to a 3rd-party company's domain. So you're right that there's definitely more to the story here than it being "not possible". Hopefully we can get another answer at some point that details how it was possible in the past and whether it is still possible.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yet, is it really on topic here? The question is not really about managing one's own website, but something external. Whatever the rules are on `fb.me` and how to use it, is mostly a problem to direct at the owning company and not really about managing a website.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I agree that a case could be made for the original question being off-topic, but I didn't feel strongly enough about it to unilaterally close-hammer it as a mod action.